# Problem throwing and catching custom exceptions in C++

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I've created the class *Someting* which throws an exception *SomethingException* (SomethingException inherits from std::exception) when it fails to instantiate. the problem is I can't catch *SomethingException* as such (I had to do a dirty trick to catch it).

There is somewhere in the program where it executes:
**This doesn't work**, the exception is not caught and the program crashes.

```
try{
    Something* s = new Something();
}
catch (SomethingException* e){
    std::cerr<<e.what();
}
```

In contrast this **does** work (exception is caught and the correct message shown) but I really have the feelin I shouldn't be doing this

```
try{
    Something* s = new Something();
}
catch (std::exception* e){
    SomethingException* e2 = (SomethingException*) e;
    std::cerr<<e.what();
}
```

Because the pointer is casted I can only make this work if and only if one type of exception is thrown. The moment I need to catch various types this won't work.

Is there a way to caught a custom exception in a more correct way?

Edit:

The exception is thrown as follows

```
//...
throw new SomethingException ("Errormessage"); //Custom exception constructor
//...
```

The declaration of Something::Something() is

```
Something::Something() throw(...)
```

Using the declaration

```
Something::Something() throw(SomethingException)
//or
Something::Something() throw(SomethingException*)
```

Throws a lot of warnings (Warning C4290)

Comment: Why are you throwing a pointer instead of [by value](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.12)?

Comment: Your code feels like you are a Java programmer starting in C++. The way you use exceptions is not the usual C++ way.

Comment: Note: It is easier to derive exceptions from std::runtime_error than std::exception. This is because std::runtime_error will store the error message (passed in the constructor) for you that is returned by the what() method. Note: MSVC has a non standard std::exception that allows you to pass the error message in the constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general it's best to throw exceptions by value and catch them by reference:

```
try {

    throw SomethingException();

} catch (const SomethingException& error) {

    std::cerr << error.what() << '\n';

}
```

You would only be able to catch an exception with `catch (SomethingException*)` if you were to throw it with `throw new SomethingException()`. There isn't enough information in your question to tell, but the problem may be in how `SomethingException` derives from `std::exception`. Verify that or change it to inherit from, say, `std::runtime_error` or `std::logic_error` instead.

Also, don't use `throw` specifiers. Just don't. No compiler affords any benefit to using checked exceptions: in effect, *checked exceptions aren't checked* except to fail horribly (throwing `std::bad_exception`) in the event of an exception that doesn't conform to the specifier. That's probably what's happening in your code.

Comment: > throw new SomethingException() is the way is thrown. I'll try what you say anyway

Comment: This time it doesn't compile at all. 'std::runtime_exception doesn't have a default constructor' also the compiler throws a warning saying 'omitting exception specification except to assert the function is not  __declspec(nothrow)' <-- rough translation

Comment: @NeonMan: The `runtime_error` and `logic_error` constructors take a `string` message, and `what()` must have the `throw()` specifier if you overload it.

Comment: Tried made SomethingException not inherit from anything and doesn't catch it either. I'm also not comfortable with the compiler warnings regarding the 'trhow(SomethingException)' in the function declarations.

It seems like I can only throw basic types since changing every exception to plain ints works but I need the extra info contained in the exception (not shown on this case bacause it failed before trying to iplement it).

Comment: @NeonMan: You should get rid of the `throw(SomethingException)` specifier on the function. There's really no reason catching a user-defined exception should fail to work, and there's not enough information in your post to tell where your problem is.

Comment: So you suggest a throw(...) specifier on the function declaration and a using "throw SomethingException();" inside the function? or directly throwind a default exception like "throw std::exception()"?

Comment: @NeonMan: I suggest *no throw specifier whatsoever* on the function declaration and, yes, `throw SomethingException();` in the function body.

Comment: It kinda works, i can throw the exception but can only catch it with "catch (...)". I'm giving up un retrieving any information from the exception (a la Java) and only use them to break the execution. I've tried to catch the exception with all combinations of &/*/const and no one except (...) works so I noticed subclassing exceptions in c++ is pretty much useless. Thankyou for all the advice you gave me.

Comment: @NeonMan: That's really strange. Are you using an old compiler? *Something* is causing the incorrect behaviour.

Comment: I'm using MSVC 2010 and made it work by not really catching the exception (catch(...){}) the purpose is breaking the constructor but I wanted to get some info on why the constructor broke, hence the custom exception. What I was looking for (by subclassing exceptions) was something similar to Python/Java exceptions but as I've seen, there's nothing like it on C++.

Comment: @NeonMan: As far as you've seen there isn't, but in reality there is. :P

Answer (score 7):

For others who may have the problem where a custom exception, derived from std::exception, is being thrown but not caught, also check:
- That the inheritance is public
- If your exception is declared in another DLL, that the exception class is exported from the DLL.  Strangely, if it is not, this does not produce a link error (in VS2012), it just fails to be caught.

Comment: This helped with GCC too (adding `public` after `:` in custom exception declaration).

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the code where you throw the exception.

Another point is about throw-specifications - it's generally a bad idea. The problem is that C++, unlike Java, doesn't insist on throw-specs and so you get next to no benefit from them. All that they can do is potentially cause a core dump if your code (or some code that you call) throws an exception that isn't specified in the throw-spec

Comment: Added the throw line. I really like the way java uses the exceptions, unlike c++. Preventing an object for being constructed is essential in this case and, using a custom exxception is preferred.